# How do I setup prefix-based keyboard shortcuts in kwin and/or KDE?

Tags: kde, kwin

I'd like to set up some kwin keyboard shortcuts that would only work when you first press a prefix. Just like `Ctrl-a` in screen or `Ctrl-b` in tmux. For example, I'd like to press `Ctrl-=, 1` and have current window move and resize to the left half of the screen. Window management functionality seems to be there (*"Quick Tile Window to the Left"*) but I don't seem to be able to define prefixed shortcuts, at least not from the GUI. I can see that default panel keyboard shortcuts are prefixed (`Alt-D, A`) - this would suggest that the other part of functionality is also there :)

Context: I'm trying to get partial functionality of [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) for OSX. I have it configured with `Ctrl-=` as prefix, and different commands are by now ingrained in my muscle memory :) I don't really use the grid bit, but half/quarter shoves are thing I use every day. If kwin (or kde) itself doesn't offer such functionality, I'm happy to use some extra software to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I'm working on the same thing and I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to do this :[